# How to output csv data to column by column

Tags: php, mysql

With this code I can get data from mysql database and save it to .csv format.

```
<?php
$filename = 'text.csv';
header('Content-type: application/csv');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$filename);

$host="";
$uname="";
$pass="";
$database = ""; 
$connection=mysql_connect($host,$uname,$pass); 
echo mysql_error();

//or die("Database Connection Failed");
$selectdb=mysql_select_db($database) or die("Database could not be selected");  
$result=mysql_select_db($database)
or die("database cannot be selected <br>");

$sqlagentdetails = "select * from users WHERE company_name != ''";
$rowresult = mysql_query($sqlagentdetails); 

echo "Coloumn 1";
echo "Column  2";
echo "\n";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rowresult, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
    $myQuery =  mysql_query( /* query are goes to here...*/ );

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($myQuery)){  

    $postcode = "{$row['postcode']}";  
    $paddress = "{$row['paddress']}";

    echo "$emailAgent  $paddress" . "\n";

    }
}
?>
```

It's successfully save data to .csv format but problem is when I view the .csv file. It's showing the result look like this :

```
--------------------------
Column 1        Column 2
-------------------------
result 1 result 2
result 1 result 2
result 1 result 2
result 1 result 2
```

BUT TI'S SHOULD BE SHOW LIKE THIS **(IT'S MUST SHOW EACH VALUE TO EACH COLUMNS NOT 2 VALUE TO EACH COLUMN)**

```
--------------------------
Column 1        Column 2
-------------------------
result 1       result 2
result 1       result 2
result 1       result 2
result 1       result 2
```

How do i save this .csv file result to column by column ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want a <kbd>TAB</kbd> between the columns, put it in the `echo` statements:

```
echo "Column 1\tColumn 2\n";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rowresult, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
    $myQuery =  mysql_query( /* query are goes to here...*/ );

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($myQuery)){  

        $postcode = $row['postcode'];  
        $paddress = $row['paddress'];

    echo "$postcode\t$paddress" . "\n";

}
```

There's also no need to wrap the array references with `"{...}"` when that's the whole string.

Comment: Showing same result..I mean view is same. It's cross the column 1 value to column 2 ..NOt column by column.

Comment: I don't understand. The only difference I can see between your two results is the separator between the columns.

Comment: You were using the wrong variable, `$emailAgent` should have been `$postcode`.

Comment: Oh it's not a problem I changed it.problem is when I'm viewing the csv file. did you saw the url ?

Comment: I downloaded that file, I don't see a problem in it.

Comment: In CSV.. column 1 = email and Column 2 = postcode. Now you see that when you view the csv file..It's showing email address over Column 2, right ?

Comment: No. The email addresses are in column 1.

Comment: Is your issue that the email addresses are long, so they extend under the Column 2 heading? That doesn't matter for CSV format, it doesn't care about the field lengths. It just cares about the separator between fields.

Comment: Please see this image..now You can understand what i'm saying..http://propertyjungle.com.au/correct-view.gif

Comment: When you import the file into the spreadsheet, make sure you tell it to use TAB as the column delimiter. It looks like it didn't recognize it automatically.

Comment: No..it's don't need to widen the columns. it's automatically show the result column by column. I've another example..

Comment: Now I'm using this `echo "Column 1 \t Column \n";` and `echo "$emailAgent \t $paddress \n";`. It's appearing a `?` in csv file. Do you know why ?

Comment: That's what I was talking about. It's not recognizing the `\t` as the column delimiter. The Import dialog should let you tell it what you're using as the delimiter.

Comment: So what should i do now or how do i do this, Barmar ?

Comment: I don't know. It's not a programming problem, it's an issue with your spreadsheet. Find out what it expects as the delimiter (maybe comma), and use that in your script.